# Download file uploaded to Azure Storage in Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage

I got the code to upload a document to Azure storage.

```py
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container_name, blob_name)
blob_client.upload_blob(file_content, overwrite=True)
absolute_path = f"https://{container_name}.blob.core.windows.net/{blob_name}"
```

And the file gets uploaded to a link like this :

`https://projectName.blob.core.windows.net/attachments/16/document1.pdf`

But how do I download it ?
When I try to `curl --head` the URL I get :

`Could not resolve host: projectName.blob.core.windows.net`

Comment: Is the source blob in the same storage account as the target account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use `blob_service_client` for download as well? taken from [Download a blob with Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-download-python#download-to-a-file-path)

```
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container_name, blob_name)
with open(file=os.path.join('filepath', 'filename'), mode="wb") as sample_blob:
    download_stream = blob_client.download_blob()
    sample_blob.write(download_stream.readall())
```